# Max response size with ajax-request

Tags: yii2, yii2-advanced-app

When response size is too large Yii2 add to response message ('An internal server error'). Example: Client size:

```
$.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/site/index',
        async: false,
        success: function (data) {}
    });
```

site/index:
variant1:

```
echo '12345';
```

result: 12345

variant2:

```
echo '123451231242352345345234'; #10000 symbols
```

result: 123451231242352345345234...An internal server error.

If I duplicate this code without Yii2, this working fine.
How can I increase max response size limit in Yii2?

UPD: Problem with output_buffering value in php.ini file. In my config this value is 4096

Comment: What is the internal server error? Check your logs.

Comment: exception 'yii\web\HeadersAlreadySentException' with message 'Headers already sent.

Comment: this does not look like what you are thinking can you add the actual code that is throwing the response to the ajax cal

Comment: Problem with output_buffering value in php.ini.
This value in my config is 4096